# List all equivalence classes of associate elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ are associates iff $a|b$ and $b|a$.
$\mathbb{Z}_{12} =\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$.  I know I can brute force this and check every pair of elements, but is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ are associate if and only if they generate the same (principal) ideal in $\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$, i.e. if they differ by a *unit* factor.

Now units in  $\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$ are the congruence classes of integers coprime to $12$ – namely $\;\{1,5,7,11\}$.

For instance $\{2,10\}$ is the list of associates of $2$,  $\{3,9\}$ of associates of $3$.

Comment: So are {1,11}, {2,10}, {3,9}, {4,8}, {5,7}, {6,0} the pairs of associate elements?

Comment: Not exactly: all units are associate, and  $6$ is associate only to itself.

Comment: so we have {1,5,7,11} make up one equivalence class and the rest of the rest are the pairs {2,10}, {3,9}, and {4,8}?

Comment: And the singleton $\{6\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

$a|b$ means $b=ka$ where $k$ is an integer.

$b|a$ means $a=lb$ where $l$ is an integer.

Hence $a=kla$, what can you say about $k$ and $l$?

Comment: Can you say $kl=1$?

Comment: yup. furthermore, $k$ and $l$ are integer.

Comment: so $k=-l$.  So $b = -a$?

Comment: $(k,l)=(1,1)$ or $(k,l)=(-1,-1)$, we must have $|b|=|a|$, and immediately, we can check that the all relation pair is of the form of $(x,x)$.

Comment: No : you only have $kl\equiv 1\mod 12$.